# Conditional action based on whether any file in a directory has a ctime newer than X

Tags: bash, file, backup, amazon-s3

I would like to run a backup job on a directory tree from a bash script if any of the files have been modified in the last 30 minutes. I think I can hack together something using `find` with the `-ctime` flag, but I'm sure there is a standard way to examine a directory for changes.

I know that I can inspect the ctime of the top level directory to see if files were added, but I need to be able to see changes also.

FWIW, I am using [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) to backup directories to S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time in minutes, you should use `-cmin -n`

```
find /some/start/dir -cmin -30 -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes to files already in the directory do not cause a change in the directory's timestamps, so you need to check the files inside (e.g. with `find` as you suggest).